# Want to delete the dynamically appended card from object array using splice method but the loop iteration is getting wrong values

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, append

I am making a task planner using classes.

These tasks are saved in the form of dynamically appended cards.

I am adding three cards in the array in class CardManager.

When I am selecting a card to delete by pressing a delete button the id is retrieved correctly, but in the last `delfunc` function which has a `for` loop, I am getting wrong array length.

So splice is not working.

The problem is in the loop of last function called `delfunc()`.

```
class Card {
    constructor(id, cname, pic, description, assignee, dDate, st) {
        this.id = id;
        this.cname = cname;
        this.pic = pic;
        this.description = description;
        this.assignee = assignee;
        this.dDate = dDate;
        this.st = st;
        // this.info=info;
    }
}
class CardManager {
    constructor() {
        this.cardArr = [];
        this.currentId = 1;
    }
    addcard(cname, pic, description, assignee, dDate, st) {
        const nCard = new Card(this.currentId++, cname, pic, description, assignee, dDate, st); //creates 
        an instance of class card
        this.cardArr.push(nCard);
    }

}
const cardDeck = new CardManager(); //create an instance of card manager to access the members


// cardDeck.addcard("laundry","test","testing","Saeed","thursday","to do");
let tname = document.querySelector("#text1"); //accepting user input from form
let tdes = document.querySelector("#des");
let assignee = document.querySelector("#assignee");
let dDate = document.querySelector("#dDate");
let sTatus = document.querySelector("#stAtus");


let addButton = document.querySelector("#addButton");

addButton.onclick = function () {
    alert("here i am card deck");
    cardDeck.addcard(tname.value, "test", tdes.value, assignee.value, dDate.value, sTatus.value);
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
}


let btn1 = document.querySelector("#btn1");
let buttonCount = 1;

btn1.onclick = function displayListHtml() {

    let html = "";
    alert(cardDeck.cardArr.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < cardDeck.cardArr.length; i++) {
        html = `<div class="card">
                   <h1>${cardDeck.cardArr[i].cname}</h1>
                   <img src="sample.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
                   <p>${cardDeck.cardArr[i].description}</p>
                   <p>${cardDeck.cardArr[i].assignee}</p>
                   <p>${cardDeck.cardArr[i].dDate}</p>
                   <p>${cardDeck.cardArr[i].st}</p>
                   <p>${cardDeck.cardArr[i].id}</p>
                   <p><button class="delete btn btn-primary" id="dbutton_${cardDeck.cardArr[i].id}"> 
                   Delete</button></p>
                   <p><button class="Edit btn btn-primary" id="ebutton_${cardDeck.cardArr[i].id}"> 
                   Edit</button></p>
                   </div>`;
        buttonCount++;
    }
    const taskcontainer = document.querySelector("#taskcontainer");
    const element = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(html);
    element.querySelector("button.delete")
        .addEventListener("click", delfunc);
    element.querySelector("button.Edit")
        .addEventListener("click", edifunc);
    //  element.addEventListener("click",yourClickEventHandler);
    taskcontainer.append(element);
}

function delfunc() {

    alert("i am in delete function");
    const taskElement = event.target.closest(".delete"); //see line 74.
    let delIdArr = taskElement.id.split("_"); //spliting the id by underscore. i.e . dbuton_id 
    let retreiveId = delIdArr[1];

    for (let j = 0; j < this.cardDeck.cardArr.length; j++) {
        if (retreiveId === j) {
            this.cardDeck.cardArr.splice(retreiveId, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. You example is too complicated.

Comment: when I am clicking on delete button on card ,the card "id" is retrieved correctly ,I have checked it using alert but the loop iteration is giving me wrong values,it is more than the actual number of cards pushed in array.The array lenght is not showing the correct lenght of array.So splice is not working

Comment: Your comment is not a [mcve]. Try to narrow the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function delfunc() {
        alert("I am in delete function");
        const taskElement = event.target.closest(".delete");//see line 74.
        let delIdArr = taskElement.id.split("_"); 
        let retrieveId = delIdArr[1];
        var arr=[];

        for (let j = 1; j <= cardDeck.cardArr.length; j++ ) {
              if (retrieveId == j) {
                  arr = cardDeck.cardArr.splice(retreiveId, 1);
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is minimal version your concern. But looks like `splice` call doing as expected.

```js
const del = (cardArr, retreiveId) => {
  for (let j = 0; j < cardArr.length; j++) {
    if (retreiveId === j) {
      cardArr.splice(retreiveId, 1);
    }
  }
};

const cardArr = [2, 3, 4];
// delete the index 1
del(cardArr, 1);

console.log(cardArr);

// Case where delete index out of array index
const a = [1];
del(a, 1)
console.log(a);
```

Comment: my concern here is the loop is iterating more than the size of cardArr.I am pushing 3 cards and the loops is itaterating 6,7,and so on so splice could not be executed .